# How to avoid nested keys and values while joining tables and using 'for json auto'

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to retrieve some data from joined tables in JSON format. 
Currently I'm trying this:

```
select top(1) 
    a.IdUser , 
    b.UserName , 
    a.IdGroup , 
    c.Title 
from UserGroupMembers as a 
inner join users as b on a.IdUser= b.iduser 
inner join UserGroups as c on a.IdGroup = c.IdUserGroup
for json auto
```

which returns this:

```
[{"IdUser":1,"IdGroup":8,"b":[{"UserName":"User1","c":[{"Title":"Group1"}]}]}]
```

while I need to get this:

```
[{"IdUser":1,"IdGroup":8, "UserName":"User1", "Title":"Group1" }]
```

or at least this:

```
[{"IdUser":1,"IdGroup":8,"b":[{"UserName":"User1"}] ,"c":[{"Title":"Group1"}] }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `FOR JSON PATH` instead of `FOR JSON AUTO`:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE UserGroupMembers (
   IdUser int,
   IdGroup int
)
CREATE TABLE Users (
   IdUser int,
   UserName nvarchar(50)
)
CREATE TABLE UserGroups (
   IdUserGroup int,
   Title nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO UserGroupMembers(IdUser, IdGroup) VALUES (1, 8)
INSERT INTO Users(IdUser, UserName) VALUES (1, N'User1')
INSERT INTO UserGroups(IdUserGroup, Title) VALUES (8, N'Group1')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    a.IdUser , 
    b.UserName, 
    a.IdGroup, 
    c.Title 
FROM UserGroupMembers AS a 
INNER JOIN Users AS b on a.IdUser= b.IdUser 
INNER JOIN UserGroups AS c on a.IdGroup = c.IdUserGroup
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[{"IdUser":1,"UserName":"User1","IdGroup":8,"Title":"Group1"}]
```

Note, that with `FOR JSON PATH` you may use dot-separated column names to generate JSON with nested objects.

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    a.IdUser , 
    b.UserName AS [b.UserName], 
    a.IdGroup, 
    c.Title AS [c.Title]
FROM UserGroupMembers AS a 
INNER JOIN Users AS b on a.IdUser= b.IdUser 
INNER JOIN UserGroups AS c on a.IdGroup = c.IdUserGroup
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[{"IdUser":1,"b":{"UserName":"User1"},"IdGroup":8,"c":{"Title":"Group1"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way

```
select *
from (
    select top(1) 
        a.IdUser , 
        b.UserName , 
        a.IdGroup , 
        c.Title 
    from UserGroupMembers as a 
    inner join users as b on a.IdUser= b.iduser 
    inner join UserGroups as c on a.IdGroup = c.IdUserGroup
) t
for json auto
```